# Django rest API won't filter on fields created by MariaDB view

Tags: django, django-models, mariadb

Djago rest API is not filtering on fields that were created by MariaDB view.

- selected
- cnrbillable

Works fine for native db fields as:

- swcustomerid
- swparentid

When I'm filtering on selected or cnrbillable then django is ignoring my filtering request. Can django filter on fields "created" by MariaDB view?

Django model:

```
class VwMrsCustomers(models.Model):
    swcustomerid = models.IntegerField(db_column='SWCUSTOMERID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    swname = models.CharField(db_column='SWNAME', max_length=70, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    swparentid = models.IntegerField(db_column='SWPARENTID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    selected = models.IntegerField(db_column='SELECTED', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    cnrbillable = models.IntegerField(db_column='CNRBILLABLE', default=1)  # Field name made lowercase.
    us = models.SmallIntegerField(db_column='US', default=0)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'vw_mrs_customers'
```

MariaDB view:

```sql
CREATE
DEFINER = app_mrs_reporting
VIEW vw_mrs_customers
AS
(
SELECT
    mrs_customers.SWCUSTOMERID,
    mrs_customers.SWNAME,
    mrs_customers.SWPARENTID,
    mrs_customer_settings.US,
    CASE when mrs_customer_settings.SWCUSTOMERID is null then 0 else 1 end AS SELECTED,
    CASE when mrs_customer_settings.SWCUSTOMERID is not null then mrs_customer_settings.CNRBILLABLE else 0 end AS CNRBILLABLE

FROM
    mrs_customers
    LEFT JOIN
    mrs_customer_settings ON (mrs_customers.SWCUSTOMERID = mrs_customer_settings.SWCUSTOMERID)
)
```

Django view:

```py
class CustomerSettingsList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = VwMrsCustomers.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializerSettings
    filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,
                       filters.SearchFilter,
                       filters.OrderingFilter,)
    filter_class = VwMrsCustomersFilter
    filter_fields = ('swcustomerid', 'swname', 'swparentid', 'cnrbillable', 'selected')
    search_fields = ('swcustomerid', 'swname', 'swparentid', 'cnrbillable', 'selected')
    ordering_fields = ('swcustomerid', 'swname', 'swparentid', 'cnrbillable', 'selected')
```